# How do you write an .xyz file in the Atomic Simulation Environment?

Tags: crystallography, atomic-simulation-environment

I built a supercell of a molecular crystal and wish to write an .xyz file in ASE. How do I do that? The molecule has three different types of elements, C, H, and N.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you have an atoms object, all you need to do is call the "write" function.

```
from ase import Atoms

supercell = Atoms()
supercell.write("supercell.xyz")
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the underlying function `ase.io.write()`

```
import ase.io
from ase.build import bulk

atoms = bulk('Ag')
ase.io.write('ag.xyz', atoms)
```

Using the function is more general because one could write a series of geometries to one file by providing a list of Atoms objects

```
ase.io.write('ag.xyz', [atoms, atoms])
```